# Skip Specific rows from CSV file for the CSV Datasource report generation with JasperReports

Tags: csv, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to create *JasperReports* reports based on dynamically generated CSV files.

Generated CSV file contain two different column headers. I want to omit the first header details and only need to read values from second header.

Refer the attached image.

[image: Transaction.csv]

I want to skip the first 3 rows and need to read csv from 4th or 5th row onwards.

Please note that I unable to delete first header. How can we perform this requirement to generate such report?

'AMOUNT' datatype is BigDecimal and Based on 'AMOUNT', perform several calculations also.

How can we view reports with *iReport* with this requirement?

Comment: You can create *Java* application. You can use [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources)

Comment: You can also read about [CSV Query Executer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/csvdatasource/index.html#csvqueryexecuter)

Comment: Thank you for the links(+1). JavaBean Data sources are not efficient of current requirement. We have 600 millions of transactions and also with the requirement need to use CSV data source. And also CSV datasource implementation is design with java and it is general solution. Common CSV reader for all the reports and do not specify the column names in JRCsvDataSource implementation. Reason is re-usability and provide general solution.

Comment: Are you sure that in case having deal with `600 millions of transactions` the using of *csv* is the good idea? ;)

Comment: sorry, 600 millions transactions per day is the maximum case, we are generating hourly reports. So nearly 25 millions for one csv file.